# Using Glyphs with Amazon Location Service and Mapbox-GL

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl, amazon-location-service

I am using the Amazon Location Service with React, react-map-gl and Mapbox-GL. I can successfully load ESRI and HERE maps which suggests my authentication is OK but I seem to have trouble with accessing Glyphs (fonts). I am trying to add a cluster markers feature like [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/). I can add the points and load the base layer but when I try to add the point counts there is an error accessing the glyph. It is sending a request like this:

> https://maps.geo.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/maps/v0/maps/<MY_MAP>/glyphs/Noto%20Sans,Arial%20Unicode/0-255.pbf?<....SOME_AUTHENTICATION_STUFF>

This seems to match the request format shown here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location-maps/latest/APIReference/location-maps-api.pdf

But it responds with: `{"message":"Esri glyph resource not found"}`

I get a similar error message with HERE maps and different fonts. I have added the following to the action on the role with no success (it loads the map but not glyphs)

Tried this:

```
"geo:GetMap*"
```

And this:

```
"geo:GetMapStyleDescriptor",
"geo:GetMapGlyphs",
"geo:GetMapSprites",
"geo:GetMapTile"
```

What do I have to do to setup glyphs correctly in the Amazon Location Service? I have not configured anything just hoped they would naturally work. Have I missed a step? Can't see anything online about it.

Is there a work around where I could load the system font instead of a remote glyph?

I am using the following versions which are not the most recent as the most recent are incompatible with Amazon Location Service:

```
"mapbox-gl": "^1.13.0",
"react-map-gl": "^5.2.11",
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default font stack (`Noto Sans, Arial Unicode`) for the cluster layer isn't currently available via Amazon Location. You will need to change the font stack used by the cluster layer to something in the supported list: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location-maps/latest/APIReference/API_GetMapGlyphs.html#API_GetMapGlyphs_RequestSyntax